# Constrait number type with property Length in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

In order to avoid some regex or code, is there any constraint for number types with property length?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

Just in the case that i need to check form field for numbers between 10 and 20 for example, is there something native that allows to do that?

I guess the right way for a number type is a length or range comparison constraint.

Here's the tricky code that I'm using in my form (without entity):

```
->add('phone', TextType::class, array(
    'constraints' => new Regex(['pattern' => '/^([0-9]{9,12}+)$/']),
    'label' => false, 
    'required' => 'required', 
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-control-lg validate')
))
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the logic by yourself? `[0-9]{9,12}` is indeed a char regex. Translate that to number and you have a range bewteen 100000000 (smallest number on 9 position) and 999999999999 (highest number on 12 positions)

Comment: i did not think about that, but it's an option. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$min = 9;
$max = 12;

->add('phone', NumberType::class, array(
    'constraints' => new Range([
        'min' => 10 ** ($min - 1),
        'max' => (10 ** $max) - 1,
        'minMessage' => "You need to enter at least $min characters",
        'maxMessage' => "You need to enter no more than $max characters"
    ]),
    'label' => false, 
    'required' => 'required', 
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-control-lg validate')
))
```

This checks that a number is between 9 and 12 characters long (inclusive) by using the smallest 9 digit number and greatest 12 digit number as boundaries.

Be careful though when handling phone numbers as number types, usually it is less error prone to use strings instead. Since you do not need to calculate with phone numbers, using strings is okay. With an integer, you cannot support special characters like '+', '/', and '-'. You also run the risk of running into overflows.

Comment: The Range type doesn't works for numbers between this range, but not for phone numbers for example, that's why i'm using regex for only accept numbers and count the lenght of the form. I will try with your code in order to see the result, thanks.

Comment: The code snippet is not using RangeType, but the Range constraint. If this snippet does not work for you, can you clarify what exactly the problem is you're facing?